# Add image from website to Frame in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to make a Frame from which I want to add an image from a website.

Do I set the background as an image?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;

class NewFrame extends Frame {

  // Constructor.
  public NewFrame (int width, int height)
  {
    // Set the title and other frame parameters.
    this.setTitle ("Exercise 9.5");
    this.setResizable (true);
    this.setBackground (Color.cyan);
    this.setSize (width, height);

    // Show the frame.
    this.setVisible (true);
  }

  // Override paint():
  public void paint (Graphics g)
  {

  } 

} // End of class "NewFrame"

public class ex5 {

  public static void main (String[] argv)
  {
    NewFrame nf = new NewFrame (300, 250);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following

```
 // load the image once
 BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new URL(imageLocAsString));
 // now in paint(Graphics g) do
 g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
```

Look [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html) for more information.